# Add or Subtract Values with change event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
//code not relevant to question 

var answer_1 = parseInt(3),
    answer_2 = parseInt(1),

$radioOptions.on("change",function(){
 //additional code

    answer_1 = answer_1 + 1;

 //more code

    answer_2 = answer_2 + 1;

});
```

What happens is when a radio is clicked within a form we add 1 to that var. For example, if I click the `answer_1` radio it will add 1 to the variable making it 4.

Here is the problem I run into. There are multiple radio options. If a person clicks `answer_1` *then* clicks `answer_2` it adds 1 to both fields as they have clicked both fields.

What I need to do is only add the one for the option they choose. In other words, if they click `answer_1` it adds plus 1 to that variable. If they then choose `answer_2` it removed the plus 1 from the one they previously selected and adds plus one the the now selected option.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: **1.** Don't use `click` event on radio buttons, use `change` event
 **2.** Use `data-*` attribute to store the value on element
 **3.** Use `data()` to get the stored value

Comment: radio's have a `value`, don't use data-s where not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var selector = $('input[type=radio]');
var preElem;
selector.on('change', function () {
 ++this.value;
 if (preElem) {
  --preElem.value;
  $(preElem).parents('label').next().text(preElem.value);
 }
 preElem = this;
 $(this).parents('label').next().text(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="1">
  <input type="radio" id="1" name="test" value="1">Radio 1</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Total: <span>1</span>
<br>
<label for="2">
  <input type="radio" id="2" name="test" value="1">Radio 2</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Total: <span>1</span>
<br>
<label for="3">
  <input type="radio" id="3" name="test" value="1">Radio 3</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Total: <span>1</span>
<br>
<label for="4">
  <input type="radio" id="4" name="test" value="1">Radio 4</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Total: <span>1</span>
<br>
```

Comment: i thought when the other radio button is checked the previous added will be removed `If they then choose answer_2 it removed the plus 1 from the one they previously selected`

Comment: its either `1 or 2` for first `2 or 3` for second and so on

Comment: i think this is what he wants based on this question

Comment: Thank you for the help. Yes, this is on the right track. Question though: I have a variable `answer_1`, `answer_2`, etc. I need to update the value of that variable. How would I do that with your answer? Also, the value can be any number. If the number is, let's say 4, then when the person selects it, it should go up by one, IE: 5. Make sense?